# Can't setup a Wired Network in ArchLinux Fresh Install

Tags: linux, terminal, ip, systemd, archlinux

I first decided to install Linux by moving from Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (updates were up-to-date), with old Acer unpopular motherboard, DDR3 12GB, Intel i5, GTX 1050Ti, and without TPM module and built-in WiFi adapter, to ArchLinux (01.01.2023 version), by extracting to a flash drive using Rufus for Windows.
I formatted the USB flash drive (around 6GB free space without ISO-file) in GPT format with a large cache, unpacked the image (during this procedure, Rufus offered me to update the libraries, which I agreed to), got into ArchLinux's BootManager, selected the first line of the setup (x86-64), and everything except the "systemd-networkd-wait-online.service" automatically loads successfully.
I have already prepared the distribution disk, by formatting the disk from which I downloaded ArchLinux (I have backup copies of Windows on other disks) under the Linux system according to the guide on YouTube.

But after that, the first problems began. The "ping" command works just awful, which makes it impossible for me to install the necessary files, which needed to install the system afterwards.

I have been experimenting for 17 hours now, almost non-stop trying to find at least some solutions, but nothing helps (and this problem has been relevant for decades on forums, and none of these answers helped me). The only thing that helps a little is the "ip link" command. I used to link ip "localhost" and dev "lo", because that's the only data the "ip a" command gives me. After that, I could connect to DNS servers with the "ping" command, and catch only one packet per attempt to enter the command, and even if I entered the IP (not in letters) of some website, for example "google.com", then nothing worked, as it was before the "ip link" command. By the way, "ping localhost" always worked fine, and I had a nice Internet speed, when I had a working OS.

I tried to create a static IP, but could not do anything to raise the "state". Using the "ip" command does not change anything, and commands like "ifconfig", "nmcli" and many others simply do not work, most likely due to the lack of necessary files that I cannot download using this computer. The system clock is correct at first glance, but out of sync. All possible items that can block access to the Internet are disabled in the built-in UEFI menu. There is nothing left of Windows from the connected drives (SSD SATA-III (240GB), HDD (1TB)) on the computer, with the exception of the Windows recovery partition (around 100MB) on the HDD.

Unfortunately, I don't have any wireless Internet adapter, but if there is no way without it, then I can buy it. I have a MiWiFi Router, and the settings on their site is good, and I even set Google and Cloudflare DNS servers, which didn't help.
Any changes in any files don't make sense and mostly have been replaced instantly. After reboot, any changes are reset to default.

My NVIDIA GPU was with "NVIDIA STUDIO" drivers installed earlier.

When trying to enable "dhcpcd" or "systemd-networkd-wait-online.service", it starts spamming with one error with a pause, saying:

```
root@archiso ~ # [ OK ] Stopped Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector..

Starting Refresh pacman mirrorlist with Reflector....

[FAILED] Failed to start Refresh Pacman mirrorlist with Reflector.. See 'systemctl status reflector.service' for details.
```

I tried to configure the configs of these services, but to no avail. And the command itself, which is advised to write a 'systemctl status reflector.service', gives only this afterwards:

```
..reflector.service: enabled; preset: disabled) <...> Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) <...>  Process: ...(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)...".

The "journalctl" command shows errors like this:

"Unstable clock detected, switching default tracing clock to "global"...

r8169 0000:03:00.0: unknown chip XID 481, contact r8169 maintainers (see MAINTAINERS file)

ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000400-0x000000000000047F (\PMIO) (20220331/utaddress-204

ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000047F (\GMIO) (20220331/utaddress-204)

ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GMIO) (20220331/utaddress-204)

ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000500-0x0000000000000563 (\GMIO) (20220331/utaddress-204)

lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich

cfg80211: Process '/usr/bin/set-wireless-regdom' failed with exit code 1.

at24 15-0050: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator

controlC1: Process '/usr/bin/alsact1 restore 1' failed with exit code 99.

controlC0: Process '/usr/bin/alsact1 restore 0' failed with exit code 99.

controlC2: Process '/usr/bin/alsact1 restore 2' failed with exit code 99.

kauditd_printk_skb: 36 callbacks suppressed

kauditd_printk_skb: 10 callbacks suppressed

systemd-networkd-wait-online[357]: Timeout occured while waiting for network connectivity.

systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Failed to start Wait dor Network to be Configured.

Reached target Network is Online.

Switching to fallback DNS server 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com.

error: failed to retrieve mirrorstatus data: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

And I got what it says, but really don't know what to do now.

I still want to fully and feature-richly try Linux, after the final disappointment in the lack of good customization in Windows (I'm not a hater, I just like to redo everything for myself), and I don't really want to go back there. That's why I turned here. I hope for your support, and sorry if there is a lot of text, I would just get bored of sending so much information separately.

Answer (score 0):

You have the needed information in the log, why didn't you follow the hint?
r8169 0000:03:00.0: unknown chip XID 481, contact r8169 maintainers (see MAINTAINERS file)

Support for this chip version was removed because there was no hint that it really exists. For now you can downgrade the kernel or install vendor driver r8168.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah guess what, you're not alone, this chip was "known" and working before the latest update.

```
2023-03-05T18:59:26.743961-05:00 symphony kernel: [    1.503167] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168f/8111f, f8:0f:41:62:07:db, XID 481, IRQ 26
2023-03-05T18:59:26.743962-05:00 symphony kernel: [    1.503175] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
```

But now you get:

```
2023-03-05T20:51:31.454817-05:00 symphony kernel: [    1.522054] r8169 0000:02:00.0: unknown chip XID 481, contact r8169 maintainers (see MAINTAINERS file)
```

To fix that you have to:

- get another computer
- get r8168-dkms from here: https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/r8168-dkms/download
- transfer it to your computer with a usb stick or whatever
- install it, then, to be sure:
- sudo apt-mark hold r8168-dkms
- create "/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-r8169"
- write "blacklist r8169" in it.
- reboot

Ta-da! LAN port lights up again.